# How to get the file name having more then one extension in c#

Tags: c#

I am having file name as below.
i need only sample.xml as result.
sample.xml.jued.783737377365474.da

Please help me on this. thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you tried?  A combination of `Path` utilities and string manipulation seems reasonable here.

Comment: Try to split your sting by "."

Comment: yes but i need result as sample.xml.

Comment: yes but Try to split your sting by "."

Comment: [String.LastIndexOf Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wdsy8fy(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Boopathi show us how you get the file name and what you at least tried, to get the expected result.

Comment: Please read this article: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File name can have *one* extension only:

```
string path = "sample.xml.jued.783737377365474.da";

// ".da"
var ext = Path.GetExtension(path);
```

However, in case you have a `origin.extension.[some data].da` pattern, you can split the file name by `.` and take *first two items*:

```
// sample.xml
var origin = String.Join(".", Path
  .GetFileName(path)
  .Split(new char[] { '.' }, 3)
  .Take(2));
```